# Problem with interface of Parabolic Equation Toolbox (PETOOL) for Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulator, propagation

Perhaps some of you used PETOOL. It is available here (for free): [here](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AEJS_v1_0.html)

Looking at some tutorials and manual found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465511002669), the interface should look like this:

[image]

My interface however looks like this:[image]

I am missing all the variable parameters that apparently should be there. I have never used this software before, so perhaps I am missing something obvious? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? Do you get any errors or warnings in the command window when running it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem in 2018b.   I opened up the GUI for mainwindow.fig in GUIDE and saw that panels were covering all of the buttons.   If you right click on each panel and then "send to back", it will move the panel object to the background.   Then resave the figure.